# Convert mixed string (containing utf8 char and utf16 char) into utf8 string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, utf-8, decode, encode, utf-16

I want to convert mixed string like this "Dаtе" where "a" is in **utf16 (1072 decimal)** into **utf8 (97 decimal)**:

```js
const mixedString = "Dаtе";
const expectedString = "Date";

const toCharCodes = (str) => {
 return Array.from(Array(str.length).keys()).map(i => str.charCodeAt(i));
}

console.log(toCharCodes(mixedString)); // [68,1072,116,1077]
console.log(toCharCodes(expectedString)); // [68,97,116,101]
console.log(mixedString === expectedString) // false;
```

How to convert utf8/utf16 strings to utf8?

Comment: What about looking into using the [TextDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/TextDecoder)?

Comment: I've tried to use it this way, but it does not work:
`code
const uint8array = new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode("Dаtе");
const string = new TextDecoder().decode(uint8array);
console.log(uint8array,string );
console.log(string === "Date") // false;
`
Any Idea?

Comment: This has nothing to do with UTF-8 vs. UTF-16. The character U+0430 (decimal 1072) is from the Cyrillic alphabet. It looks the same in most (?) fonts and it is historically related to the Latin letter "a", but it's really a different letter today, at least when stored digitally on a modern system.

Comment: It's a problem similar to confusing "0" and "O" (digit "zero" and letter "oh"), which look indistinguishable in some fonts.

Comment: Make sense, indeed. 
Do you have any solution to convert the whole string into utf8 for getting U+0061 for the "a" and U+0065 for the "e" there?

Comment: This looks like creatively fabricated input to trick the human eye; it's probably hard to come up with a general solution. One approach would be to disallow letters from different scripts. You'll need some library that gives access to Unicode properties.

Comment: Have you any suggestion, I'm really lost.

Comment: Try https://opensourcelibs.com/lib/cyrillic-to-translit-js or https://www.npmjs.com/package/transliteration (if applicable). Seek for more at [48 Open Source Transliteration Software Projects](https://opensourcelibs.com/libs/transliteration)